# Hibernate - updating object with many to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have class Person and class Role. There is many to many bidirectional relationship between Person and Role. If I create new Person, load existing role from db and set the role to the Person, it works. But if I load existing Person from db (already has some roles), load another role from db, set the role to the person - I get org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: Role.

I don't know where is the problem.

There is my hbm.xml

```
<class name="Person" table="person">
  <id column="ID" name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property column="Name" name="name" type="string"/>
  <property column="Surname" name="surname" type="string"/>
 <property column="Email" name="email" type="string"/>    
 <set  name="roles" table="role_person" inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all">
    <key column="Person_ID"/>
    <many-to-many class="Role" column="Role_ID"/>
 </set>
</class>

<class name="Role" table="role">
  <id column="ID" name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property column="Name" name="name" type="string"/> 
  <set name="people" table="role_person" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
    <key column="Person_ID"/>
    <many-to-many class="Role" column="Role_ID"/>
  </set>
 </class>
```

My code:

```
Person person1 = LoadObjects.getPerson( with some ID); // this person has already role author
Person person2 = LoadObjects.getPerson( with another ID); // this person has already role owner 

Role roleOwner = LoadObjects.getOwnerRole();
Role roleAuthor = LoadObjects.getAuthorRole();
```

// this conditions don't work properly, they are always true, even if they shouldn't, but in this example they should be true

```
if (!person1.getRoles().contains(roleOwner)) {
        person1.getRoles().add(roleOwner);
}
if (!person2.getRoles().contains(roleAuthor)) {
        person2.getRoles().add(roleAuthor);
}

SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

session.saveOrUpdate(person1);
session.saveOrUpdate(person2);

session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

There is getOwnerRole method:

```
 public static Role getOwnerRole() {
    Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
    s.beginTransaction();
    List a = s.createQuery("from Role where name = 'Owner'").list();
    Role role = (Role) a.get(0);
    Hibernate.initialize(role.getPeople());
    s.close();
    return (Role) a.get(0);
 }
```

Comment: can you show the code of `LoadObjects.getOwnerRole();` if you are using `load` method inside.. try with `get`

Answer (score 0):

In your HBM mapping some errors. thought definatel thats not cause of the issue.

```
<class name="Person" table="person">
  <id column="ID" name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property column="Name" name="name" type="string"/>
  <property column="Surname" name="surname" type="string"/>
 <property column="Email" name="email" type="string"/>    
 <set  name="roles" table="role_person" inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all">
    <key column="Person_ID"/> // This Should be ID As person id column name is ID..
    <many-to-many class="Role" column="Role_ID"/>// This Should be ID As well as ROLE id column name is ID..
 </set>
</class>

<class name="Role" table="role">
  <id column="ID" name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property column="Name" name="name" type="string"/> 
  <set name="people" table="role_person" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
    <key column="Person_ID"/>// This Should be ID As ROLE id column name is ID..
    <many-to-many class="Role" column="Role_ID"/>// This Should be ID As well, as People  id column name is ID..
  </set>
 </class>
```